# Can Visual Studio Code `quick fix` interact with keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vim-plugin, vscodevim

I am using *VS Code* with the excellent *vscodevim* extension.  When I navigate to a code that has a *Quick Action* available I can `ctrl` + `.` to activate the drop down context menu.

Is there a way to select toggle through the list of available items using the keyboard - other then the arrows keys.  As a point of information, within *Visual Studio* it is possible using `tab`, this does not work in *VS Code*.

---

Why? 'cause I love my MS ARC keyboard but I hate the rocker arrow keys.

Comment: Relevant VS Code issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/55111

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue for linux users using vscode with advanced shortcuts like vim extension in your case, for some reason quick fix contextual menu is unattached from vscode shortcuts which makes shortcuts not work. A really easy workaround to use with a graphical interface is HotKey.
HotKey > https://github.com/autokey/autokey for Linux and create your own shortcut.
[image: How to Use HotKey]

Comment: I guess I should update this question at some point ... the Arc keyboard died and I've switched to the _neovim_ plugin so I could port over my `vimrc`.  My current setup requires a _vscode_ solution as I regularly switch between _windows_, _wsl2_ and _linux_ .  The problem still exists, is is possible to use _autokey_ to 'tab' through _inteliisense_ options that are determined at runtime?

Comment: @THBBFT Yes, you can since it emulates any key from your keyboard. For example to avoid moving my left hand out of "home row" from the keyboard I used alt+f/e/d/s to simulate arrow keys, which you can navigate anywhere in vs code. BTW you can create a more advanced and customized extension or shortcuts to your keyboard. Even add an exception to work on specifics application, as I did to only work mine on vs code!